# How to pass a std::pair of iterators to a function template and have the iterator types deduced?

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, range, std-pair

I am trying to wrap two iterators into a std::pair and pass that into a function argument but want the type of the iterators to be generic.

The pair itself it templatized on the iterator type...

```
template<typename Iterator>
using iteratorPair = std::pair<Iterator,Iterator>;
```

...then the template function itself has the signature...

```
template<typename T, typename U,template<typename> class IteratorPair, template<typename> class IteratorPairInt>
void
sortUsingIndicesToTargetContainerPair(
    const IteratorPair<T>& rangeToSortSource,
    const IteratorPair<T>& rangeToSortTarget,
    const IteratorPairInt<U>& indicesRange)
{ ...}
```

I am doing all of this so that I can call the function with brazed initialization...

```
std::vector<int> vecs{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
std::vector<int> indices{9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0};

auto copy = vecs;
sortUsingIndicesToTargetContainerPair({vecs.begin(), vecs.end()},
                                      {copy.begin(), copy.end()}, 
                                      {indices.begin(), indices.end()});
```

I can get this to work if I explicitly construct the type by using its name when calling the function, but if possible would like to used braced initialization.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Is there any reason for passing the iterators as pair? stl usually pass the iterators as they are: e.g the `std::vector::insert` overloads for ranges https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert . Your call would look like `sortUsingIndicesToTargetContainerPair(vecs.begin(), vecs.end(), copy.begin(), copy.end(), indices.begin(), indices.end());` then.

Comment: I suggest using a true range-type instead of iterator-pair, also take a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/subrange

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest the solution below.
Idea: instead of trying to direct deduction of types, add an adapter function that converts arrays of arguments into pairs of iterators:

```
template<typename T, typename TIndex, std::size_t N>
constexpr void FAdaptor
(
    const T(&rangeToSortSource)[N],
    const T(&rangeToSortTarget)[N],
    const TIndex(&indicesRange)[N]
)
{ 
  static_assert(2 == N, "must be pair");    
  
  sortUsingIndicesToTargetContainerPair
  (
    IteratorPair<T>(rangeToSortSource[0], rangeToSortSource[1]),
    IteratorPair<T>(rangeToSortTarget[0], rangeToSortTarget[1]),
    IteratorPair<TIndex>(indicesRange[0], indicesRange     [1])
  );  
}
```

The full example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

template<typename Iterator>
using IteratorPair = std::pair<Iterator,Iterator>;


template<typename T, typename TIndex>
void sortUsingIndicesToTargetContainerPair
(
    const IteratorPair<T>& rangeToSortSource,
    const IteratorPair<T>& rangeToSortTarget,
    const IteratorPair<TIndex>& indicesRange)
{ 
    
}

template<typename T, typename TIndex, std::size_t N>
constexpr void sortUsingIndicesToTargetContainerPair2
(
    const T(&rangeToSortSource)[N],
    const T(&rangeToSortTarget)[N],
    const TIndex(&indicesRange)[N]
)
{ 
  static_assert(2 == N, "must be pair");    
  
  sortUsingIndicesToTargetContainerPair
  (
    IteratorPair<T>(rangeToSortSource[0], rangeToSortSource[1]),
    IteratorPair<T>(rangeToSortTarget[0], rangeToSortTarget[1]),
    IteratorPair<TIndex>(indicesRange[0], indicesRange     [1])
  );  
}


int main() {
  std::vector<int> vecs{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
  std::vector<int> indices{9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0};

  auto copy = vecs;
  sortUsingIndicesToTargetContainerPair(std::make_pair(vecs.begin(), vecs.end()),
                                        std::make_pair(copy.begin(), copy.end()), 
                                        std::make_pair(indices.begin(), indices.end()));

  sortUsingIndicesToTargetContainerPair2({vecs.begin(), vecs.end()},
                                         {copy.begin(), copy.end()}, 
                                         {indices.begin(), indices.end()});
 
  std::cout << "ok\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've already defined `iteratorPair<Iterator>`, you don't need `template<typename> class IteratorPair`.

I'd also suggest taking (pairs of) iterators by value. Do you take (pairs of) pointers by const reference?

```
template<typename T, typename U>
void sortUsingIndicesToTargetContainerPair(
    iteratorPair<T>& rangeToSortSource,
    iteratorPair<T>& rangeToSortTarget,
    iteratorPair<U>& indicesRange);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues:

- `{..}` has no type, and can only be deduced as `std::initializer_list<T>` or as `T(&)[N]`.
- template argument cannot deduce alias as alias,

  i.e. `iteratorPair<SomeType>` (aka `std::pair<SomeType, SomeType>`) won't match `template <typename> class Pair`.

  We got similar "issue" with default template (`std::vector<T, Allocator /*=SomeDefault<T>*/>` for `template <typename T> Container`) which has been resolved in C++17. I don't think that a resolution can be possible for aliases which might have "conflicts"/duplicates.

  As mentioned by Caleth, you probably don't want to have deduction on that anyway.
- Your `iteratorPair` seems to define a range, but your constness is misleading. a `const iteratorPair<std::vector<int>::iterator>` allows to modify underlying container. using a true range type seems more appropriate.

To allow your calling syntax, you might get rid of `std::pair` and do:

```
// SourceIt might be different than TargetIt (iterator and const_iterator mainly)
template <typename SourceIt, typename TargetIt, typename IndexesIt>
void sortUsingIndicesToTargetContainerPair(
    const SourceIt (&rangeToSortSource)[2],
    const TargetIt (&rangeToSortTarget)[2],
    const IndexesIt (&indicesRange)[2])
{ /*...*/ }
```

But, to keep your idea of ranges, you might even do

```
template <typename Source, typename Target, class Indexes>
void
sortUsingIndicesToTargetContainerPair(
    const Source& rangeToSortSource,
    Target& rangeToSortTarget,
    /*const*/ Indexes& indicesRange)
{ /*...*/}
```

And you even have simpler calling syntax:

```
sortUsingIndicesToTargetContainerPair(vecs, copy, indices);
sortUsingIndicesToTargetContainerPair(my_sub_range(vecs, /*..*/),
                                      my_sub_range(copy, /*..*/),
                                      my_sub_range(indices, /*..*/));
```

Comment: It is not a good idea to use an array of two elements here: `... void sortUsingIndicesToTargetContainerPair(const SourceIt (&rangeToSortSource)[2], ...` because it's easy to make a mistake when calling by omitting the second iterator: `sortUsingIndicesToTargetContainerPair({vecs.begin()}, ...` <=> `sortUsingIndicesToTargetContainerPair({vecs.begin(), vecs.begin()}, ...`.

Comment: @B0FEE664: Good point. I suggest you enrich your answer with this pitfall avoided with your extra `N` (which seems over complicated).